# Gitlab shared runners: env variables privacy with docker runners

Tags: security, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci-runner

[**Disclamer**] : this post focus exclusively on CI / **build** aspects and has nothing to do with CD / **deployment**

Say I have a project hosted on Gitlab involving some source code compilation. For the present purpose, let's say I wan't **Maven** to create two cars (`STAGE` `PROD`) of some java project every time a developer merges on master. Those cars:

- will be stored on the project registry
- need to contain the **environment variables** defined for this project.

Can I legitimately assume that those **environment variables** will remain safe (i.e. private) if the project is compiled with  **shared gitlab runners** based on the assumption that `Docker` runners are ephemeral ? Is there a (better) way to enforce privacy despite using shared runners?

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative would be using [Protected environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#protected-environment-variables).
[issue 1452](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/1452) show them in  "CI/CD" panel of Settings.

[image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/uploads/5882608e96ba07c951c2cb3e4c27621b/Screen_Shot_2019-01-09_at_11.07.18_AM.png]

By prefixing them with `STAGE_` or `PROD_`, your maven job could use the right variable depending on the current car.
By their protected nature, they would not be exposed.